# Need help with frequencies in the UK

Tags: uk, frequencies

I'm recording in London next week. All my wireless systems run from 500.00-560.000. Will I have any problems in that area of the UK with these frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

Channel 38 and 70 are the only legal channels in the UK. Additional frequencies, like the ones you mention can be purchased as a special short licence. Check out the licensing authority website http://www.jfmg.co.uk/ to get your licence and more info.